# MEDIAN() in Vertica SQL

Tags: sql, median, vertica

I have a Vertica table as:

```
my_day, price
'2016-10-01', 55
...
```

Both columns are encoded as VARCHAR.

I need to find the median price per day, so I tried

```
select distinct my_day, median(cast(price as numeric)) over (partition by my_day)  
from schem01.my_test_table 
where  my_day between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-10' 
group by my_day, cast(price as numeric);
```

However, this returns a very high value which is around 2-3x the actual median which I manually calculated and tested.

Anyone know what's going on with the median here?

Comment: just remove `group by my_day, cast(price as numeric);` from the query. the window function takes care of the grouping. because you are already using `distinct` that would get you the expected result.

Comment: I owe you a beer, kind sir. This fixed it.